# How to keep only the doube quote part in a string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

I want to keep only the double quote part of a string in javascript. Suppose this is my string:

`const str = 'This is an "example" of js.'`

I want my result like that:

**`output = example`**

Means I want to keep only the **`example`** part which is in the double quote. 
I can remove the double quote from string but I haven't found any good way to keep only the double quote part of a string.

Comment: That is not a valid string. Either escape the double quotes or using single quotes within the double quotes.

Comment: please make an attempt before asking, if you've made an attempt please provide a [mcve]

Comment: first convert this into valid string, after that you will able to apply action. ex: `const str = 'This is an "example" of js.'`

Comment: You can actually escape the double quotes by placing a \ in front of it. Here's how that would look. const str = "This is an \"example\" of js."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the start and last index of `"` and then use `slice`.

```js
const str = 'This is an "example" of js';

const startIdx = str.indexOf('"');
const lastIdx = str.lastIndexOf('"');

const output = str.slice(startIdx+1, lastIdx);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use a regex capturing group like so:

`const captured = str.match(/\"(.*)\"/)`

but you'll need to declare the string with single quotes and then double quotes inside like this:

`const str = 'This is an "example" of js.'`

try it here: https://regexr.com/4hfh3

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, this is not a valid string, you need to escape inner double quotes `const str = "This is an \"example\" of js."`

After that you can extract the value inside the quotes with a regex:

```
const matches = str.match(/"(.*?)"/);
  return matches ? matches[1] : str;
```